# How to keep the tab open in accordion after page refresh ( after submit) using Jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

for example, I have my second tab open in accordion. After the page refresh, I still want the second tab open, how can I achieve this?

thanks.

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any behavior you want persisting after a true page refresh will most likely have to leverage `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, because a true page refresh will complete wipe JavaScript memory.  Alternatively, if you can add a query string on the URL on successful submit you could sniff around for that as a means of capturing some state.  But honestly, all of these are sort of work arounds-- if you want persistent behavior, probably better to submit with an AJAX solution and avoid a page refresh in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**document.location.reload()** stores the position, but it is not mentioned [in the docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Add additional `true` parameter to force reload.

`document.location.reload(true)`